# Root access denied in LiveUSB of Porteus

Tags: root, live-usb

I am on Live Linux USB of Porteus linux and I copied it to RAM.

I want to access root folder for making changes so that settings gets saved.

but this is showing up[image: Root Access denied]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](https://forum.porteus.org/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=1062), the default root password is **toor**.

If you can log in as root using that password, you should be able to access that folder. If you are logged in as a guest, then from the command line you can switch to root with the command `su root`, and then enter root's password. As root, you should be able to access the folder you are trying to access. Additionally, running a file manager like *dolphin* should give you access through a GUI file manager.